# VNC is Getting disconnected in aerokube moon

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, vnc, aerokube-moon

i deployed moon aerokube on my k8s cluster, i enabled vnc option on my code, but i am unable to see the test execution on the VNC in question, and i got the following error :

[image]

I would like to know why ?

in addtion, i will give the logs of each container of the pod related to the session lanched by my program:

```
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $ kubectl -n moon logs -f chrome-88-0-09941471-c519-4562-a50c-15d028b67437 -c browser
Starting ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}) on port 4444
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $ 
============================
scode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $ kubectl -n moon logs -f chrome-88-0-09941471-c519-4562-a50c-15d028b67437 -c defender 
2022/10/07 11:58:38 headless mode: false
2022/10/07 11:58:38 listening on :4545
2022/10/07 11:58:38 waiting for webdriver
2022/10/07 11:58:39 webdriver started in 723.391863ms
2022/10/07 11:58:39 proxy POST to http://127.0.0.1:4444/session]
2022/10/07 11:58:40 proxy POST to http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/47fcc1192a20549578edd3f5142f02be/url]
2022/10/07 11:58:41 proxy GET to http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/47fcc1192a20549578edd3f5142f02be/title]
2022/10/07 11:58:41 proxy GET to http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/47fcc1192a20549578edd3f5142f02be/screenshot]
2022/10/07 12:00:21 received terminated (15) signal
2022/10/07 12:00:21 graceful shutdown in 30s
2022/10/07 12:00:21 http: Server closed
2022/10/07 12:00:21 exited
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $
============================
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $ kubectl -n moon logs -f chrome-88-0-09941471-c519-4562-a50c-15d028b67437 -c x-server 

X.Org X Server 1.21.1.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux chrome-88-0-09941471-c519-4562-a50c-15d028b67437 5.4.0-1090-azure #95~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Aug 14 20:09:27 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1090-azure root=UUID=11ae0071-786c-4dd3-96b1-7b92873c6b43 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 earlyprintk=ttyS0
xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Oct  7 11:58:38 2022
(++) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $
===============================
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $ kubectl -n moon logs -f chrome-88-0-09941471-c519-4562-a50c-15d028b67437 -c vnc-server
07/10/2022 11:58:38 passing arg to libvncserver: -passwd
07/10/2022 11:58:38 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbport
07/10/2022 11:58:38 passing arg to libvncserver: 5900
07/10/2022 11:58:38 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 12
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Using X display :0
07/10/2022 11:58:39 rootwin: 0x50e reswin: 0x200001 dpy: 0x86dbe670
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 ------------------ USEFUL INFORMATION ------------------
07/10/2022 11:58:39 X DAMAGE available on display, using it for polling hints.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   To disable this behavior use: '-noxdamage'
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39   Most compositing window managers like 'compiz' or 'beryl'
07/10/2022 11:58:39   cause X DAMAGE to fail, and so you may not see any screen
07/10/2022 11:58:39   updates via VNC.  Either disable 'compiz' (recommended) or
07/10/2022 11:58:39   supply the x11vnc '-noxdamage' command line option.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Wireframing: -wireframe mode is in effect for window moves.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
07/10/2022 11:58:39   errors, etc) it may be disabled:
07/10/2022 11:58:39    - use '-nowf' to disable wireframing completely.
07/10/2022 11:58:39    - use '-nowcr' to disable the Copy Rectangle after the
07/10/2022 11:58:39      moved window is released in the new position.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
07/10/2022 11:58:39   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
07/10/2022 11:58:39   periodic repaints.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 XFIXES available on display, resetting cursor mode
07/10/2022 11:58:39   to: '-cursor most'.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   to disable this behavior use: '-cursor arrow'
07/10/2022 11:58:39   or '-noxfixes'.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 using XFIXES for cursor drawing.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 GrabServer control via XTEST.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Scroll Detection: -scrollcopyrect mode is in effect to
07/10/2022 11:58:39   use RECORD extension to try to detect scrolling windows
07/10/2022 11:58:39   (induced by either user keystroke or mouse input).
07/10/2022 11:58:39   If this yields undesired behavior (poor response, painting
07/10/2022 11:58:39   errors, etc) it may be disabled via: '-noscr'
07/10/2022 11:58:39   Also see the -help entry for tuning parameters.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   You can press 3 Alt_L's (Left "Alt" key) in a row to 
07/10/2022 11:58:39   repaint the screen, also see the -fixscreen option for
07/10/2022 11:58:39   periodic repaints.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 XKEYBOARD: number of keysyms per keycode 7 is greater
07/10/2022 11:58:39   than 4 and 51 keysyms are mapped above 4.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   Automatically switching to -xkb mode.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   If this makes the key mapping worse you can
07/10/2022 11:58:39   disable it with the "-noxkb" option.
07/10/2022 11:58:39   Also, remember "-remap DEAD" for accenting characters.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 X FBPM extension not supported.
Xlib:  extension "DPMS" missing on display ":0".
07/10/2022 11:58:39 X display is not capable of DPMS.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 --------------------------------------------------------
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Default visual ID: 0x21
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Read initial data from X display into framebuffer.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 initialize_screen: fb_depth/fb_bpp/fb_Bpl 24/32/3584
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 X display :0 is 32bpp depth=24 true color
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5900
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Listening for VNC connections on TCP6 port 5900
07/10/2022 11:58:39 listen6: bind: Address already in use
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Not listening on IPv6 interface.
07/10/2022 11:58:39 
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Xinerama is present and active (e.g. multi-head).
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Xinerama: number of sub-screens: 1
07/10/2022 11:58:39 Xinerama: no blackouts needed (only one sub-screen)
07/10/2022 11:58:39 

X11 MIT Shared Memory Attach failed:
  Is your DISPLAY=:0 on a remote machine?
  Suggestion, use: x11vnc -display :0 ... for local display :0

caught X11 error:
07/10/2022 11:58:39 deleted 28 tile_row polling images.
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Serial number of failed request:  52
  Current serial number in output stream:  82
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $ 
==========================
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir $ kubectl -n moon logs -f chrome-88-0-09941471-c519-4562-a50c-15d028b67437 -c video-recorder
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.1 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 20220219
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm -lz' --extra-ldexeflags=-static --enable-gpl --enable-static --enable-small --enable-avfilter --enable-libx264 --enable-libxcb --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-w32threads --disable-alsa --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-librtmp --disable-devices --disable-debug --disable-asm --enable-indev=xcbgrab
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, x11grab, from '127.0.0.1:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1665143919.415154, bitrate: 142442 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 896x414, 142442 kb/s, 12 fps, 12 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] profile High, level 2.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] 264 - core 163 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=12 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/user/Downloads/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 896x414, q=2-31, 12 fps, 12288 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame= 1222 fps= 12 q=-1.0 Lsize=      97kB time=00:01:41.58 bitrate=   7.9kbits/s speed=   1x     
video:82kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 18.394022%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] frame I:7     Avg QP: 9.23  size:  6048
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] frame P:309   Avg QP: 6.46  size:    52
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] frame B:906   Avg QP:10.68  size:    28
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  0.5%  0.0% 98.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] mb I  I16..4: 54.6% 40.4%  5.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.9%  L0:78.7% L1:21.3% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] 8x8 transform intra:34.7% inter:1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 3.8% 1.5% 1.2% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] i16 v,h,dc,p: 76% 18%  5%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 57%  6%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 35% 13%  2%  4%  5%  4%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] i8c dc,h,v,p: 99%  1%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.3% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] ref P L0: 55.5%  0.0% 44.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] ref B L0: 53.8% 46.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] ref B L1: 96.0%  4.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f2d3e8bab30] kb/s:6.57
Exiting normally, received signal 15.
Uploading /home/user/Downloads/test.mp4 to s3://videos/automation/2022-10-07/test.mp4
upload: Downloads/test.mp4 to s3://videos/automation/2022-10-07/test.mp4
vscode ➜ /workspaces/workdir 
============================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change the image of x-server container to `aerokube/xvfb-server`